# Show several words randomly with php

Tags: php, random, count, words

I need to show automatic words when loading a page on my site. I have managed to show a word, but I can not see more than one. It is important that the words do not repeat themselves.

I have this code where I specify each word.

```
<?php


$randomThings = array(
    'random thing 1',    
    'random thing 2',    
    'random thing 3',    
    'random thing 4',    
    'random thing 5',    
    'random thing 6',    
    'random thing 7 ',    
);

?>
```

And finally I paste this code where I want it to be displayed.

```
<?php echo $randomThings[mt_rand(0,count($randomThings)-1)]; ?>
```

As I say, a word shows it to me correctly but I want to show more than one.

Thank you very much, sorry for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the snippet, provide number of elements as second parameter in rand_keys:

```
<?php
  $input = array(
    'random thing 1',    
    'random thing 2',    
    'random thing 3',    
    'random thing 4',    
    'random thing 5',    
    'random thing 6',    
    'random thing 7 ',    
  );
  $rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
  echo $input[$rand_keys[0]];
  echo $input[$rand_keys[1]];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it this way :

```
<?php echo array_shift( $randomThings ); ?>
```

The `array_shift()` method takes the first element of an array and take it out of the array.

If ou want to make it random, you can use the `shuffle()` function on your array to shuffle it before doing the array_shift.

here is the php doc for [shuffle()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)
here is the php doc for [array_shift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

Answer (score 1):

Just shuffle, and then pop or shift:

```
<?php

$things =
[
    'The early bird catches the worm.',
    'Two wrongs don\'t make a right.',
    'Better late than never.'
];

shuffle($things);

while($item = array_pop($things))
    echo $item, "\n";
```

Example output:

```
Better late than never.
The early bird catches the worm.
Two wrongs don't make a right.
```

Or make a generator:

```
$generator = function($things) {
    shuffle($things);
    return function() use (&$things) {
        return array_pop($things);
    };
};

$thing = $generator($things);
echo $thing();
```